# Radioisotope beta decay generator

Tags: electricity, radiation, power, radioactivity

Why are there no electrical generators utilising the electron/s of beta decay from a radioisotope for generating a working current?

For example, how much radioisotope would I need to generate 1A or higher, i.e. 1C/s = 6E18 electrons/s? Are there species that can sustain this rate of beta decay for any practical length of time, e.g. 25-40 years, say?

I envision a set up of the radioisotope firing the beta particle at a metal anode. Since this hasn't been done in practice - Why? Can beta decay be regulated (e.g. increased) by an external field or change in ambient conditions?.

Comment: Such devices exist - see 'nuclear battery' on Wikipedia for a starting point...

Comment: And "Betavoltaics". I see, they do exist. Interesting. Should I delete this question?

Comment: At what stage in a physics or electronic engineering degree do you get to learn about this topic? I intend to do a double.

Comment: You have to take either spacecraft engineering, or "insane devices for evil supervillains 101"

Comment: might do a triple? I'm half-way there with spacecraft instrument design, a la Cruise et al.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are such devices, but they are rather limited in their electrical output and do require you to carry a big chunk of radioactive material around. Ironically their only commercial use was implanted [pacemakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betacel)!

If you are going to use radiation to make energy it's easier to use a safer alpha emmitter and just use the heat to generate electricity by the thermo-electric effect. eg [New Horizons RTG](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/rps/newhorizons.cfm)